# Microsoft SQL Server - Copy column in table, modify value and type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm quite new to scripts and need some help on creating a script doing multiple actions in sequence.

Let's use this tentative (and bisarre) table to illustrate the solution. The table could potentially hold hundreds of entries:

[image: Original table]

1. I want to add a PhoneNumber column with varchar type and populate it from the existing PhoneNumber column.
2. For phone numbers consiting of 5 digits I want to add a leading zero (0) so all entries have the same length (6).
3. When this is done for all occurances of 5-digit phone numbers I want to delete the old PhoneNumber column

This is how the table should look after step 1:
[image: After step 1]

And after step 2 it should look like this:

[image: After step 2]

Finally, after the third step I want this outcome:

[image: Final result]

Can this be accomplished with a script? I don't really need the script to follow this exact sequence as long as it results in the desired outcome. This is just the sequence of actions I have thought could be an allright approach.

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using, you've tagged 2 here. What have *you* tried so far and why isn't it working?

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @heisjef . . . Your question doesn't make sense.  You have marked the phone number as a `bigint`, but numeric types do not store leading zeros.  What is the real data type?

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are absolutely right, I added the zero to illustrate that was the very problem but I see how that was confusing after all. I updated the images now, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

Remember, you can't have 2 columns called the same

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME] ADD PHONENUMBERCHAR char(6); --Adds a new column
GO;
UPDATE [TABLENAME] SET PHONENUMBERCHAR = RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', PHONENUMBER), 6); --Updates the value
GO;
ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME] DROP COLUMN PHONENUMBER --Deletes the old column
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you.. What if I'd also like ONE valid format to be 3 characters of length, and the rest 6? How can I keep strings of 3 characters the way they are and set the rest to 6 characters? I also want a value of 0 to remain 0 and not 000000

Comment: I am trying to do this. Without the `ELSE` it works for entries with length > 5. But with the else everything is copied as they were:

`UPDATE table
SET PhonenumberChar = 
CASE WHEN LEN(PhoneNumber) > 5 THEN (RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', PhoneNumber), 6)) 
ELSE PhoneNumber
END`

@Larnu

Comment: @heisjef You are not too far from a working solution. I just did some adjustments `UPDATE [TABLENAME] SET PhonenumberChar =  
CASE 
WHEN LEN(PhoneNumber) = 3 OR PhoneNumber = 0 THEN CONVERT(varchar(6),PhoneNumber)
ELSE (RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', PhoneNumber), 6))
END`

Comment: Great! It's now working as expected. Thank you so much @Esteban.

Answer (score 1):

If the value is really an integer, you can use `format()`:

```
select id, phonenumber, format(phonenumber, '000000')
from t;
```

You may want to add this as a computed column:

```
alter table t add phonenumber_6 as (format(phonenumber, '000000'));
```